# Varios Request con EF Core en Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo una WebApi Rest en .Net Core donde uso EntityFramework Core, hago una petición y funciona muy bien, el lío esta cuando hago dos peticiones al mismo tiempo, al parecer solo soporta una a la vez, si hago dos me genera el siguiente error adjunto.

```
Se ha producido una excepción no controlada por el usuario: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException    
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in LaboratorioWebApi.dll but was not handled in user code:     
'An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point.'
```

La verdad no entiendo ese error ni se que debo cambiar, apenas empiezo con .Net Core y EntityFramework Core, estoy usando inyección de dependencias.

Agradezco me puedan guiar para saber que debo hacer en esos casos.

En mi Startup este es el metodo donde hago la inyección.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
           services.AddMvc();

            var laboratorio = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DbInfo:Laboratorio");
            var soft = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DbInfo:Soft");

            services.AddDbContext<LaboratorioContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(laboratorio));
            services.AddDbContext<SofContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(soft));

            // Inyeccion de Dependencias            
            services.AddSingleton<EquipoRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<TipoEquipoRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<MarcaRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<EmpleadoRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<RangoRepository>();
        }
```

y este es el context

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LaboratorioWebApi.Models
{
    public class LaboratorioContext : DbContext
    {
        public LaboratorioContext(DbContextOptions<LaboratorioContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Equipo> Equipo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EquipoDetalle> EquipoDetalle { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Laboratorio> Laboratorio { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Marca> Marca { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Rango> Rango { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Responsable> Responsable { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TipoEquipo> TipoEquipo { get; set; }
    }

    public class SoftContext : DbContext
    {
        public SoftContext(DbContextOptions<SoftContext> options)
        : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Empleado> Empleado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan colaborar. De antemano gracias

Comment: publica tu código :D

Comment: Hola @fredyfx dame 1 minuto y lo publico

Comment: @fredyfx ya quedo el codigo, agradezco me puedas colaborar.

Comment: podrías colocar todo el Start Up que tienes por favor?

Comment: Por favor incluye el error completo. El error que recibes debe ir acompañado de un stack trace más completo con muchos más detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estás accediendo a una misma instancia de `DbContext` desde varios hilos al mismo tiempo. Hacer eso no es correcto, porque `DbContext` no está diseñado para que sus instancias sean usados desde más de un hilo. Cada hilo necesita usar una instancia separada de `DbContext`.

Aunque no es 100% claro con el código que incluístes, pero creo que es razonable asumir que tus repositories están diseñados para recibir el `DbContext` en sus respectivos constructures usando dependency injection. Esto en sí no es un problema.  El problema es que estás configurando tus repositories como singletons.

O sea que si 2 hilos necesitan hacer una consulta por medio de uno de tus repositories, ambos hilos van a recibir la misma instancia del repository, lo que por extensión significa que ambos hilos van a user la misma instancia de `DbContext`. Esto no es correcto y te va a causar el error que recibes.

Tal vez exista una mejor manera de arreglar esto, pero en tu lugar, yo probaría cambiando la configuración de los repositories para que sean *transient* en vez de *singleton*:

```
services.AddTransient<EquipoRepository>();
services.AddTransient<TipoEquipoRepository>();
services.AddTransient<MarcaRepository>();
services.AddTransient<EmpleadoRepository>();
services.AddTransient<RangoRepository>();
```

Y por supuesto, si has configurado otras clases como *singleton* que a su vez tienen una dependencia, directa o indirecta, a los repositories, estas también las cambiaría para que sean *transient*.

Comment: Hola sstan muy agradecido con tu respuesta, con solo cambiar el singleton por AddTransient funciono todo de 10. No agregue el resto de código pq pensé que con eso era suficiente, gran error. 
Tengo una duda, dices que cambie las clases, sin cambiar las clases me ha funcionado pero que le debería cambiar a la clase? cuales clases?? las del repository o la del context?

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido y disculpa por la confusión con lo del *cambiar la clase*. A lo que me refería es que, si además de los repositories, también tuvieras otras clases configuradas como singletons, ejemplo: `services.AddSingleton<OtraClase>()`, y si esta clase `OtraClase` tuviera una dependencia directa o indirecta a algún repository, entonces también seria necesario cambiar `OtraClase` para que sea transient en vez de singleton.  No parece ser tu caso, pero lo mencioné por si acaso. Espero que sea un poco mas claro.

Comment: si mucho mas claro, yo deje todo lo que tenia como singleton y lo pase a AddTransient y funciona de maravilla, raro que en los tutoriales de la web muestren siempre como singleton, casi me saco un ojo de la cara xD, normalmente en un WebService habran varias peticiones y es mejor como AddTransient.